# parsing html to get only specific tags

Tags: html, wordpress, parsing, web

i need to parse this html code to get only the image src and thetext after the  tag.

`[caption id="attachment_16734" align="aligncenter" width="672"]<a href="http://myeduplus.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/consumatori.jpg"><img class="wp-image-16734 size-full" src="http://myeduplus.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/consumatori.jpg" alt="" width="672" height="480" /></a> La mucca: consumatore primario o erbivoro[/caption]`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following code you will get only the image tag and the text just beside it.

```
$input='[caption id="attachment_16734" align="aligncenter" width="672"]<a href="http://myeduplus.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/consumatori.jpg"><img class="wp-image-16734 size-full" src="http://myeduplus.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/consumatori.jpg" alt="" width="672" height="480" /></a> La mucca: consumatore primario o erbivoro[/caption]';
$str=strip_shortcodes(strip_tags($input, '<img>'));
echo $str;
```

NOTE : Here I take $input as a variable with the string. That might be get_the_content() or anything else.

Hope this will work for you.